# Destroy Object completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on angularjs $modal. i am storing values in controller as below,

```
 if($scope.mediacontent){
 delete $scope.mediacontent;}
 $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url] =media_data;
 $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url][img_no].active=true;
```

Now when next time $modal is opened I want to to destroy media content Object but with `delete` Object is not destroyed Completely.

How to destroy delete `$scope.mediacontent` Object Completely.

Comment: I guest you have declared the model in die views as well, so destroying it within a certain scope is not possible. You can rewrite it with another object. Or you can remove the DOM-nodes and rewrite the object.

Comment: The code you provided causes errors which you should be seeing in your console. The first line, `delete $scope.mediacontent={};` produces: "SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference." You cannot delete and assign in the same statement.

Comment: @JAAulde oh my mistake, i was trying  delete $scope.mediacontent , i paste it wrong here.

Comment: @anam your edited code will also cause an error because `$scope.mediacontent` is now undefined (the reference it held has been removed). You should be seeing "TypeError: undefined is not an object" in your console for line 2 of your new sample.

Comment: @JAAulde yes i am checking Object before delete .i have updated my code .

Comment: @anam That will have the same error as my last comment. The `delete` statement was not what I was pointing out. `$scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url] =media_data;` will cause "TypeError: undefined is not an object" because you deleted `$scope.mediacontent`.

Answer (score 3):

*(I'm assuming the [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068046/destroy-object-completely#comment44515796_28068046) and [other errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068046/destroy-object-completely#comment44516091_28068046) that JAAulde pointed out aren't really in your code, or that you've fixed it.)*

> but with `delete` Object is not destroyed Completely...

`delete` doesn't release objects; it removes properties. The object will be eligible for garbage collection if the property you're removing is the only reference to the object. When and how the actual garbage collection occurs is up to the JavaScript engine (it's unlikely to happen immediately). If you have *other* references to that object, then deleting the property won't make it eligible for GC (because of the other references to it).

But if you're about to assign a new value to the property, there's no reason for `delete`; assigning a new value *also* releases the reference to the previous object, making it eligible for GC (assuming nothing else has a reference to it).

E.g., this code will completely release the old object (unless something else has a reference to it):

```
$scope.mediacontent = {};
$scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url] = media_data;
$scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url][img_no].active = true;
```

...because the first line of that *replaces* the reference to the old object with a reference to a newly-created one.

Comment: hey thanx, but whats the other way to delete complete Object . cause i have  $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url][img_no].active  active , on next call i dnt have previous img_no. so i cannot make it false. I am working with carousel and at a time one array value can be active set to true.

Comment: @anam: Again: Removing the last reference to the object **does** "delete" it (make it eligible for garbage collection). It doesn't matter if the object has properties referring to other objects; those will also be eligible for GC if the object's reference to them is the *only* reference to them (and not if it isn't).

Comment: @anam: So if we have an object we refer to from `obj.a`, and `obj.a.foo` refers to another object, then `delete obj.a;` releases the reference to the first object. If that's the only reference, it becomes available for GC. If that object's `foo` property is the only reference to the second object, then the second object also becomes available for GC.

Comment: i tried setting it to {} . still   $scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url][img_no].active value persist.

Comment: @anam: You're claiming that `$scope.mediacontent = {};` and then `console.log($scope.mediacontent[$scope.slider_url][img.no].active);` does something other than trigger an error? If so: That's impossible, something *else* is happening, not that. Create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), during the course of which you'll figure out what's really happening (or you'll have something we can help you with).

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be impossible if `$scope` had a setter function for `mediacontent` that did something weird, but I doubt that's the case.